# Rails 3.1 - options_from_collection_for_select() pass in a value from a nested attribute as the option text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a select_tag like this:

```
<%= select_tag "User Groups", options_from_collection_for_select(@user_groups, "id", "name") %>
```

Here's my model

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity 
end
```

The caveat is that there is no attribute called "name" for the UserGroup model, but there is one for the Entity model.

Ideally, I would like to pass in the values from the "name" attribute in the Entity model into the options_from_collection_for_select() method... something like this:

```
<%= select_tag "User Groups", options_from_collection_for_select(@user_groups, "id", @user_groups.each{|user_group| user_group.entity.name}) %>
```

But then I get something like this:

```
[#<UserGroup id: 1, entity_id: 3, created_at: "2012-03-15 02:36:28", updated_at: "2012-03-15 02:36:28">, #<UserGroup id: 2, entity_id: 4, created_at: "2012-03-15 02:42:36", updated_at: "2012-03-15 02:42:36">] is not a symbol
```

Is there a way I can use options_from_collection_for_select() and pass in a value from a nested attribute as the option text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add this to your UserGroup model:

```
def entity_name
  self.entity.name
end
```

You can then do

```
<%= select_tag "User Groups", options_from_collection_for_select(@user_groups, "id", "entity_name") %>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could create the `entity_name` method using [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) - `delegate :name, :to => :entity, :prefix => true`

Comment: Ah thanks, Ken.  That worked perfectly!  Methods in the model is the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

`options_from_collection_for_select` also accepts a lambda as the `text_method` parameter.

```
<%= select_tag "User Groups", options_from_collection_for_select(
      @user_groups, 
      "id", 
      lambda { |user_group| user_group.entity.name} ) 
%>
```

If you have some view-specific code you don't want to pollute the model with, this allows you to put your custom method in the view instead.